# jquery .next() not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, shortcut

Im using the js shortcut plugin [shortcut.js](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/shortcut.js) to enable keyboard shortcuts for the up and down arrows to select tabs. When a tab is clicked, it is selected. Click a tab and use the up and down arrows to choose a neighboring tab. I'm using `.prev()` and `.next()` to control the selection, but something is wrong with `.next()`. When a tab is selected, the selection just skips to the last tab.

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/maqiheja/3/edit?html,css,js,output

**JS:**

```
shortcut.add("up",function() {
  $('.tab').each(function(){
    var selected = $(this).hasClass('selected');
    var end = $('.tab:first-of-type').hasClass('selected');
    if((selected === true) && (end === false)){
      $(this).removeClass('activeTab selected');
      $(this).prev().addClass('activeTab selected');
    }
  });
});

shortcut.add("down",function() {
  $('.tab').each(function(){
    var selected = $(this).hasClass('selected');
    var end = $('.tab:last-of-type').hasClass('selected');
    if((selected === true) && (end === false)){
      $(this).removeClass('activeTab selected');
      $(this).next().addClass('activeTab selected');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your looping over all the tabs. When you get to the selected tab, you make the next one selected. Then the next loop moves it again to the one after that, and so on. Get rid of the loop, find the selected tab, and make the next one selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop. Just move the selected tab to the next tab once.

```
shortcut.add("down", function() {
    var selected = $('.tab.selected');
    var end = $('.tab:last-of-type').hasClass('selected');
    if (selected.length && !end) {
        selected.removeClass('activeTab selected');
        selected.next().addClass('activeTab selected');
    }
});

shortcut.add("up", function() {
    var selected = $('.tab.selected');
    var end = $('.tab:first-of-type').hasClass('selected');
    if (selected.length && !end) {
        selected.removeClass('activeTab selected');
        selected.prev().addClass('activeTab selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why you are using `selected.length`?

Comment: `length` is the number of objects in the collection. If the selector didn't match anything, it will be `0`, which is equivalent to `false`.